# Android 10 (Q) MediaScanner Bad performance after downloading a file via DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager, mediastore, android-mediascanner

After Downloading a mp3 file via android `DownloadManager`, Downloaded songs are not added quickly to the MediaStore database. Downloaded songs are not displayed in applications such as Google Music (Play Music), etc. And the phone needs to be restarted. Why?

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mp3Url));
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); // deprecated!
request.setTitle(title);
request.setDescription(description);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "song name.mp3");
//request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))); // no longer access path on api 29 and higher
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Try this: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html Here's a rough overview on Android 10: 1. Insert a pending placeholder with metadata to `MediaStore`, 2. download the file to the returned `Uri`, 3. remove pending flag from `MediaStore` entry. (`collection` would be [`MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Downloads#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).)

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks, good solution. but `insert pending` method Is this a correct and principled solution or is it just a hack? Why should Google Android developers create such complexity for programmers? :/ Why don't they really come up with simpler solutions?

Comment: I think so, everything points in this direction. That's a good question for someone on the Android team. Perhaps one day there will be a nicer API in the support library. Once you get it working, you can post your solution adapted from the blog post using `DownloadManager` as answer.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Sure, thank you for your help. now, i should create `BroadcastReceiver` for DownloadManager and in `onReceive` --> 2. download the file to the returned Uri, 3. remove pending flag from MediaStore entry. ???